# How to pass null pointer (double pointer) to c function via java jni?

Tags: java, swig

There is the following function in shared library (dll):

```
intptr_t GetClassObject(void** pptr)
{
    if(!*pptr)
    {
        int value = 10;
        *pptr= &value; //here is another code like new Obj()
        return 0;
    }

    return (intptr_t )*pptr;
}
```

SWIG made the following wrapper:

```
SWIGEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_AddInSwigJNI_GetClassObject(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1) {
  jint jresult = 0 ;
  void **arg1 = (void **) 0 ;
  long result;
  
  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  arg1 = *(void***)&jarg1; 
  result = (long)GetClassObject(arg1);
  jresult = (jint)result; 
  return jresult;
}
```

java:

```
public class AddInSwigJNI {
  public final static native int GetClassObject(long jarg1);
}
```

How can I now make a null pointer in Java code and pass its address to this function?
Further, for example, I want to see the number 10 written at this pointer in java code

Comment: I guess you can do so by creating a long variable in Java and passing it to the JNI function then in the JNI code, you can cast the long variable to a void** type and pass it to the C function...

Comment: Create a c wrapper function that returns a pointer of the appropriate type. Your calling code will be much nicer.